# terminal command directory help

Tags: command-line

I am trying to figure out why I can't get into a directory. I am in terminal. when I type `ls` I get:

```
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Shinobi snap Templates Videos
```

all in blue.

then I enter `cd /Shinobi/` it says there is no such file or directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have typed an absolute path from root:
/Shinobi is the directory Shinobi in the root folder.

The correct command is `cd Shinobi` (assuming you're in the directory containing Shinobi - which you seem to be as it appears when you type `ls`)

The alternative of course would be to type the complete absolute path to the Shinobi directory - you can find out the absolute path by typing `cd Shinobi` (to get into that directory) then `pwd` to 'print working directory' - that will show you the absolute path to get there from anywhere in your system.

Answer (score 1):

You have to type `cd Shinobi/`

Type in `pwd` this will show you what directory you are in. I guess you are inside your user directory inside `/home/`

There is a big difference in `/Shinobi/` and `Shinobi/`

1. The first is an absolute path under `/` root `Shinobi/`
2. the latter is a relative path viewed from the directroy you are in.

The correct absolute path should be:
`/home/Username/Shinobi/` which is the same as `~/Shinobi/`

You can use TAB in terminal for autocomplete. This can help to avoid such mistakes.